# Docker Rest Apis using node.js

Tags: node.js, docker, boot2docker, dockerhub

How to run the docker rest apis in the localhost environment using node.js. I need to know the port settings and the urls which will be used on it etc.

Answer (score 0):

- https://github.com/apocas/dockerode
- https://github.com/mafintosh/docker-host

If you installed boot2docker it should have set a DOCKER_HOST env in which case:

```
var Docker = require('dockerode');
var host = require('docker-host');

var docker = new Docker(host());
```

Should work